# Break php process for getting js variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, extjs, prompt

I asked that question about PHP breaking.
I need stop execution of php process thread, while javascript performs get variable value operation (the code is generating by php).

Example:

```
<?php

print get("prompt('put your name here');"); 

// this will generate  $.ajax( ... data: { 'return':prompt('put your name') } ... ) 


?>
```

the PHP function ''get'' must print javascript code (return headers and content), but don't stop execution of php. He must watching a result of function from browser. (via ajax return).

**How i can stop php execution with TEMPORARY output and returning query result after php code complete.
Or... advice me any solution of this problem.**

(I need get prompt dialog result synchronously)

Thanks!

Comment: This is not how PHP works. PHP is a text output language. It has zero awareness of the browser's execution of the code it sends. You can't wait for a javascript call to complete.

Comment: i need alternative way to do that =)

Comment: This is a bit of a guess, but if you simply want to capture the user's name, inject it into the DOM (i.e. the HTML) somewhere and print the page, you should output the page via PHP and handle the rest in JavaScript. (That's what it's for.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't the way it works - you need to handle the output to/of the JavaScript and the response via Ajax as two separate requests within PHP.

i.e.: The general scheme is as follows:

1. PHP outputs the relevant HTML containing JavaScript, etc. The execution of this PHP script ends at this point.
2. The client-side JavaScript carries out the required processing and makes an AJAX call to a PHP script on the server. This can be the same PHP script (you could switch on a provided page "mode" via a `$_GET` or `$_POST` variable) or it could be a different PHP page entirely. However, it's important to realise that from PHP's perspective it's a completely different script invocation.

The key thing to remember is that HTTP is inherently stateless, so you need to ensure that you pass all of the relevant information the PHP script requires in the AJAX request.

Additionally, you should ideally ensure that there's a fallback system in place for user's that have JavaScript disabled, although that's falling by the wayside to a certain extent these days.

Comment: but i need lock print and pass get (at first). At second perform print (how it automate)?

Comment: but it have any problem. if at begining 'fwrite' operation... writing will be executed two times! if make 'if..else' statement (by GET or POST) i must declare all situations. But i need make one function with execution need code... i need have get(get(get(...))) - nested variant too... I think that problem have any way... hard, but optimal

Comment: i thinking about 'while' statement (it works, but blocks output handling..). And while with ~ infinite iterations had no perfomance

Comment: @xercool Sorry, but I can't follow what you're attempting to do. You might want to open a new question and outline the problem you're attempting to solve rather than get bogged down in the implementation details for an approach that doesn't sound feasible.

Comment: @xercool In terms of your "while" approach, this sounds ill advised - PHP isn't "interactive" in the manner you're attempting to use it for. (In general, it's not like an prompt based interpreted or event driven language if that makes sense.)

Comment: so. thanks. simply i want to release dynamic browser manipulation script

Comment: that 1/4 of that is absolutely impossible? )